# Zeroconf get txt record

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, dns-sd

i'm using [this](https://github.com/novotnyllc/Zeroconf) nuget package to discover a service on a network.

I would like to know if is it possible to access the txt record from:

`IReadOnlyList<IZeroconfHost> hosts = await ZeroconfResolver.ResolveAsync("_hid._udp.local.", scanTime);`

i want to get more informations (like devide id), of the service.

Thank you.

Regards.

Comment: Above NET v4.6.1 works .It should work.But the service you provide whether present in your system or not

Comment: i can discover the service, but i want access the txt record from that service.

Comment: Follow the link may help you     https://github.com/grandcat/zeroconf

Comment: Another link    https://www.mono-project.com/archived/monozeroconf/

Comment: If could find a way then mat use the windows managementobject